# ViewPager Auto Scroll behave strange and auto slides fastly android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have used an ViewPager Auto Scroll of images in my app.First time the viewpager slides perfectly. But when im returning back from some other fragment or activity, the viewpager auto scroll suddenly slides very fast

Here is my code

```
private static int IMAGES_VISIBLE_TIME = 3000;
int mImgsPosition = 0;
Handler mHandlerImgsAnime;
Timer swipeTimer;


 mHandlerImgsAnime = new Handler();
    swipeTimer = new Timer();
    swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHandlerImgsAnime.post(ViewPagerScroll);
        }
    }, IMAGES_VISIBLE_TIME, IMAGES_VISIBLE_TIME);




Runnable ViewPagerScroll = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mImgsPosition == adaptersize) {
           mImgsPosition = 0;
        }
        viewpager.setCurrentItem(mImgsPosition++, true);
    }
};
```

Comment: In `onResume()` method register your handler with runnable.

Comment: I tried that one it is not working

Comment: Did u register it with timer?

Comment: cancel the `swipeTimer` in `onPause()` of the activity and reset it in `onResume()`

Comment: It is working thank you arjun_sna